# Piketec TPT java automation

Tags: c, matlab, simulink

I am trying to use TPT java api, for some automation of project.

And trying to "Add step list" using function "generateTestCasesFromTestData"
but couldn't figure out where to get its first argument "ScenarioGroup".

Has some one worked on it ??

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: ... or why is this tagged MATLAB?

Comment: because TPT is used for matlab models and c code testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to create the test cases in your top level test case group you can get it like this:

TPT 13

```
com.piketec.tpt.api.Project prj = ...    
prj.getTopLevelTestlet().getToplevelScenarioGroup();
```

There is a design error in versions prior to TPT 13. You can only get the list of scenarios and scenario groups contained in the top level group of the testlet (`RemoteList<ScenarioOrGroup> Testlet.getTopLevelScenarioOrGroup()`). So you can only get the top level group by getting that list, take one of the elements and call `ScenarioOrGroup.getGroup()` to get the parent group of that element.